# How to config alive-progress reversed?

Tags: python

I can't find how to make progress bar decrease from right to left (from 100% to 0).
I saw this in showtime from alive-progress. But can't configure.
Can you help me?

```
with alive_bar(120, length=110, theme='smooth', monitor=False, elapsed=False, stats=False, spinner=None) as bar:
  for i in range(120):
    bar()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.